# Python & Pandas: Why is Dataframe created within my class empty?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

i have the function

```
import pandas as pd

class Func:
    def __init__(self, df):           
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
```

when i want to copy values into the data frame of my class with pandas.DataFrame.filter, its always stays empty:

```
mydf = Func(dftrain.filter(['x', 'y2']))
print(mydf.df)
```

The result is always:

**Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []**

But if i do it with a data frame thats not within my class it works, like this:

```
mydf = dftrain.filter(['x', 'y1'])
```

Any clues why and how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you create an instance, you do not use the passed in parameters, but simply create an empty DataFrame to assign to `self.df`.

Comment: ```self.df = pd.DataFrame()```

you forgot to assign `self.df` as the `df` in `(self, df)` or `self.df = df`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually fill in the `self.df` attribute and instead set it to an empty dataframe.

Just change the last line of the class to:

```py
        self.df = df
```